# Problema al usar .clone() y select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy pasando elementos de una seccion a otra, el gran problema que tengo, es que al clonarlo no se guarda el `option` seleccionado, simple ejemplo para que me entiendan:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="copy">
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="clone">Clonar</button>
<div id="container">

</div>



 $('#clone').on('click', function() {
     $('#content .copy').clone().appendTo('#container')
 }
```

Lo clona perfectamente, pero aun así no me guarda la información que se quedo seleccionada. Alguien sabe que prosigue o que otro metodo me recomiendan utilizar.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery tiene una limitación en la función [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).  La parte relevante traducida:

> Nota: Por razones de rendimiento, el estado dinámico de ciertos elementos de *form* (ej: datos ingresados por el usuario en un `textarea` y las selecciones hechas en un `select`) no es copiado a los elementos clonados. [...]

Pero puedes volver asignar el valor al nuevo elemento luego de que ha sido agregado a la página:

```js
$('#clone').on('click', function() {
  var original = $('#content .copy');
  var valor = original.find('select').val();
  var clon = original.clone().appendTo('#container');
  clon.find('select').val(valor);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div class="copy">
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="clone">Clonar</button>

<div id="container">
</div>
```